# Was digital pre-visualization used outside of the performance scenes in Bocchi The Rock?

Tags: anime-production, bocchi-the-rock

I am curious about the animation methods or pipeline used in everyday, normal scenes in *Bocchi The Rock!*. This would be segments like walking and talking and not [the stylized scenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Bocchi-the-rock-expressions.webm).

Based on [this interview](https://febri.jp/topics/btl_live_1/) (machine translated to English for me, but summarized [here](https://anilist.co/activity/526287812)), concert performance segments [used motion captured live performances](https://twitter.com/kawakami_yu/status/1630407606874542082?t=ozV-5JAKdH08r3Jqv23J6Q) which were then used to make a digital visualization. This animation was then framed in virtual cameras and the resulting footage was then used for hand-drawn animation blocking and keyframing.

The 2D animation in normal, everyday shots is clearly hand-drawn, and [keyframes and other production material support this](https://imgur.com/a/b4ry8Kg). However, there are some scenes in the first episode where character motion, shading, and frame composition that makes me think that some shots were digitally pre-visualized before keyframes were drawn.

Example 1: Character limb motion, skirt physics, and shadows.

[image: Example 1: Skirt motion and shading]

Example 2: An anamorphic lens-like effect as they pass the "camera".

[image: Example 2: Anamorphic lens-like effect]

**Was digital pre-visualization used outside of the performance scenes in *Bocchi the Rock!*?** Is studio use of digital pre-visualization common?

(If not, is there a reason why I am seeing the animation as being a little different from other shows that I've watched?)

Comment: Leaving as a comment since I don't have any concrete evidence, but this looks like rotoscoping. Basically what they were doing for the performances minus the motion capture part (basically capture live footage, then drawing over it). Not digital, but analog pre-visualization.